# Compatible wifi adapter for macbook pro 2017?

Tags: linux, wifi, osx, kali-linux, virtualbox

To all of those with a Macbook pro 2017,

Does anyone have a recommendation for compatible usb wireless adapters for the macbook pro 2017 model?

I have recently retired my old macbook 2011 and upgraded to the newest model, which rendered my Alfa awus036neh wireless adapter useless as it was not compatible with OSX. I have been/will be using this device for pen-testing purpose and like to have multiple interfaces up at one time so I can be connected at monitor the network at the same time. My setup is kali linux, within virtualbox, sitting on mac OSX.

Through my initial research I haven't been able to find any definite recommendations or success stories. So if anyone is using this combination and has had success, please let me know! If not, i'll do more research and try to answer back with my own findings.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing pen testing from kali, you configure passthrough/give the USB wifi interface directly to the kali VM, and it does not matter whether OSX supports the wifi chipset or not.

It should not be MacOS dealing with the wifi drivers with that configuration, it is the Linux in the VM that has got to support it.

Obviously you want this wifi adaptor as your 2nd connection. With such setup, you will still have Internet connectivity and ssh/remote connectivity to the VM while this wifi adaptor is in monitor mode.

Comment: Would this allow you to use 2 networks within kali? 1 network using NAT (mac intel chip) and 1 using passthrough (the wireless adapter)? Or would kali only be connected to the internet via 1 of these networks?

Comment: @rpanov Added to the answer.